# AngularJS 1.6.x: Cannot read property 'entry' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XH8EiFpw1eUVrRtoByeY?p=preview

I'm not sure why the error says `read property 'entry' of undefined` after upgrading from angular `1.3.x` to `1.6.x`

I've tried defining 'entry' as `var entry = {};` also tried dependency injection but it still errors out.

Here's the code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('SuperCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
    var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1O7M5gaEGlyE5gkOBARJrxJJMBYiTwz2THVjgbaTx9v8/od6/public/values?alt=json';
    var parse = function(entry) {
      console.log(entry);
                var category = entry.gsx$category.$t;
                var description = entry.gsx$description.$t;
                var title = entry.gsx$title.$t;
      return {

        description: description,
        title: title
      };
    };
    $http.get(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      var entries = response.feed.entry;
      $scope.parsedEntries = [];
      for (var key in entries) {
        var content = entries[key];
        $scope.parsedEntries.push(parse(content));
      }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Error is obviously here: `var entries = response.feed.entry;` -- check the `response` object

Comment: It's reading comprehension really, and I'm saying that in the nicest way possible, because I've been there and we've all been there.  `Cannot read property 'entry' of undefined` does not mean that **entry** is undefined. Try `console.log(undefined.entry);` in your console and next time read your error messages more carefully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
$http.get(url)
.then(function(response) {
  var entries = response.feed.entry;

  ...
});
```

You should pass through the `data` property of the response:

```
$http.get(url)
.then(function(response) {
  var entries = response.data.feed.entry;

  ...
});
```